# Joomla 2.5.7 strips away code

Tags: javascript, image, refresh, joomla2.5

I'm using a JavaScript within an article of Joomla, which is supposed auto load images every 5 seconds on that page. Initially I was unable to add JavaScript which has now been solved with the help of other users.

I now have a new problem. When JavaScript is supposed to refresh the image it is unable to load the image. I do not get a broken path symbol but neither is the image displayed. I'm attaching the code I'm using.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
     var picPaths = ['C:/wamp/www/joomla1/images/snapshots/cal01.jpeg'];
 var curPic = -1;
 var imgO = new Array();
 for (i = 0; i < picPaths.length; i++) {
    imgO[i] = new Image();
    imgO[i].src = picPaths[i];
 }
 function swapImage() {
    curPic = (++curPic > picPaths.length - 1) ? 0 : curPic;
    imgCont.src = imgO[curPic].src;
    setTimeout(swapImage, 5000);
 }
 window.onload = function() {
    imgCont = document.getElementById('alpana');
    swapImage();
 }
     // ]]></script>
```

/* this is a module with position akrudi which I call in an article like this */

```
    {loadposition akurdi}
     <p><img id="alpana" src="" height="250" width="250" />
     </p>
```

**SECOND CODE**

```
    function refresh() 
   {         
var imgsrc = document.getElementById("pic");
alert("message box"+imgsrc);
  document.images["pic"].src = "images/CB1.jpeg" + "?" + new Date().getTime();
  }
  window.onload=function(){
  setInterval(function(){refresh()}, 5000 ); //set interval onload just one time 
 }
```

Comment: **UPDATE** I've been able to add javascript using modules, by creating modules referring to a particular div id & using a div of same id in the articles. The problem I now face is that the image loads for <2 secs then shows a broken link. After 5 secs the image area gets reloaded but still no image comes up. If I run this code separately as independent html page it works fine. Can anyone point where I'm going wrong

Comment: for the image path, try using `<?php echo JURI::root() . "images/snapshots/cal01.jpeg" ?>`

Comment: @Lodder where to include the image path? within the <script> or <img> or as a <php> element? Also I'm using one more `code` as a backup

// In both these codes I get a div with img icon on top left. This div keeps getting loaded every 5 seconds. Any clues

Comment: In you javascript, like so: `var picPaths = <?php echo JURI::root() . "images/snapshots/cal01.jpeg" ?>;`

Comment: **UPDATE** The javascript code works in **Atomic** default template in the HOME page inside Joomla article. But if I open the Joomla article itself the script stops loading the image inside the article. Is this bit helpful?
@Lodder I tried adding the code but editor validates the html and makes changes in the given line **var picPaths = <?php echo JURI::root() . ?>"images/snapshots/cal01.jpeg"";**

Comment: no, you need to use this for the path:
`var picPaths = <?php echo JURI::root() . "images/snapshots/cal01.jpeg"; ?>;`

Comment: @Lodder : Thank you immensely for all your help. I was able to get the script running by using the second code and making the project from scratch again. Haven't been able to figure out why the previous Joomla website didn't work. Maybe some plugin/extension is clashing with the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you have been trying to add Javascript into a Joomla article before but try installing the [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051) plugin which allow you to add custom javascript, php and many other languages to your Joomla article.

**Update:**

I have just tested adding javascript to a module and embedding the module in an article to see whether or not the javascript actually works and it does. Sourcerer is **not** needed. You can simply add something like the following code to the **default.php** or **mod_xxx.php** of your module:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();    
$js = '$(document).ready(function(){ 
          //more javascript in here
       });';
$document->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Then embed the module as you normally would, using the `{loadposition xxx}` method

Comment: Im sorry didnt understand you. Are you saying that we cannot add a javascript in a specific article? Please clarify. I have used Sourcerer plugin too. When used with TinyMCE/JCE it doesnt include the module within the article. THanks

Comment: @alpana - To add Javascript, you need to use Sourcerer (or something similar), else it won't work. You said in your comment above that it doesn't include the **"module"** though. Are you trying to add Javascript or embed a module in the article?

Comment: some of the plugins act as modules, which its stated need to be included into the article. We write the script into the module. then loadposition it inorder to include the javascript into the article. Am i looking in the right direction? Plz help -Thnks

Comment: ahhh, I wasn't aware that you were embedding modules that already had Javascript in them. If it it ONLY Javascript you want to add, then don't do it via a module. Simply do it in the article using Sourcerer ;)

Comment: is there any non commercial plugin that does the same. Since sourcerer doesnt allow addition of javascript in articles in the free version. And i donot wish to buy sourcerer without first checking it.Thanks

Comment: Sourcerer does allow Javascript in the free version. I'm am using it on my own website ;)

Comment: I'm really confused about what you are trying to do.  Are you saying there is a module that contains js and you can't get that module to load at all? Or a plugin that has js and you can't get that plugin to load at all? Or are you attempting to directly insert js? 

Peronally I would always do it via a module not directly in an article. In an article it is not going to be reusable and also anyone in the right groups can come and edit it and mess it up.

Is the problem the <p> or is it that the code is stripped? WHat is saving in your database?

Comment: @elin, thnx for the reply. Well right now what is working for me is creation of a module which I call into a particular <div> which I embed in a article. What I would now like to know is, how to embed the javascript code into articles. Using Sourcerer & inserting the code causes html to add <p> tags into the article.

Comment: @lodder would this change in mod_xxx.php/default.php file affect all articles? I wish to access different images as mentioned in the initial question on different articles.Articles will be around 100-150. So will this soln work? What Im doing now is creating new modules, renaming them and calling them by giving the <div> in the article the same name as the one being called in the module. Am I in the right direction. Btw dear members, thnk u so much for ur help for a newbie :)

Comment: @alpana - Embedding the module in 1 article, will only affect that article, not others. If you want something more global, you might be better off using a plugin.

Comment: @lodder- every article requires a different image. Its like depending on the article only the image must be called. So as per my meager understanding I think I'll require a js code which will autoref only that particular article's image. 
How will using a plugin help in such a case, as I require customization on all articles.Please help guys i really dont want to give up. Thank you all

Comment: @alpana - I thought a plugin might be easier as it would be more global and would help with more articles but if u require customization on all then no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using JCE, you don't need any modules or plugins to make this work. In JCE > Editor Profiles select the profile you normally use, then click the Editor Parameters tab then the Advanced tab in there. You should see a setting for Allow Javascript. Turn this on and it will allow you to insert Javascript in the HTML view.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you be makine that a variable? Take a look at very simple image gallery and see how they do it. Inserting images and slide shows in articles has been done a million times there is no reason for you to be reinventing, take an existing plugin and modify it.

Comment: my requirment is that I need to add a different image to every article which is associated only to that one article. In website terms i guess it would mean that every different page would have a particular image associated with it. inserting an image is not an issue. The issue is to be able to refresh each of these images every x seconds when that particular page is being viewed. So I need a javascript (for every image)which'll be called only when that particular page is being looked at. Hope I'm not complicating things here.Thnx

Comment: Exactly so why not use something like VSIG and then if it doesn't work for you just modify it.  
http://www.bretteleben.de/lang-en/joomla/very-simple-image-gallery.html
I recently updated it minimally to work in J3   https://github.com/OfficialJoomlaBook/vsig3

Comment: I tried using the javascript that was given in bretteleben.de/lang-en/joomla/very-simple-image-gallery.html . Its giving me the same error with even your sample pics. It doesnt display the pics when added to a article.Only a shaded field where the image would have lain? Any thing Im doing wrong?

Comment: I've been using it, are you sure you have the images in the right place? I don't think it will do exactly what you are describing but you could just modify it to what you want. THe main thing is too that I wanted you to see how they are allowing options etc to make the plugin very differen in each article if that is what is desired.